# Unable to perform a Firebase query on a timestamp and receiving an empty body in response

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Can someone explain to me why I am not able to perform a simple Firebase query checking for a specific timestamp in a subcollection?
The code below works if I try to retrieve the whole document, but if I add the `where` query it just returns a 200 response with an empty body.
I have also tried to replace `db.collection` with `db.collectionGroup` and in this case I get a 500 response with the following message `Collection IDs must not contain '/'`.

Here you can see how I have structured my data and my code:

[image]

```
try {
     const reference = db.collection(`/data/10546781/history`).where("timestamp", "==", 1659559179735)
        
     const document = await reference.get()
        
     res.status(200).json(document.forEach(doc => {
         doc.data()
         console.log(doc.data())
     }))
        
} catch(error) {
    res.status(500).json(error)
    console.log(error)
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Dharmaraj Thanks for the help. Your answer was part of the solution. The other part concerned how my data was structured. The timestamp needed to be at the parent level of the subcollection document. So either outside the `realTimeData` object or the whole object needs to be flattened at the parent level.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) that creates a new array and not [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop that returns nothing. Try:

```
const reference = db.collection(`/data/10546781/history`).where("realtimeData.timestamp", "==", 1659559179735)        

const snapshot = await reference.get()

const data = snapshot.docs.map((d) => ({
  id: d.id,
  ...d.data()
}))

res.status(200).json(data)
```

---

Additionally, you need to use the dot notation if you want to query based on a nested field.

Comment: I have tried it before, but unfortunately all I get is an empty array.

Comment: @Lia189  if you want to query a nested field then you need to use dot notation. `.where("realtimeData.timestamp", ...`